# Java jsch.ChannelSftp - How to know if mkdir failed due to a directory alread existing

Tags: java, jsch

I'm using `com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp` as my SFTP client.

I would like to attempt to create a directory, and if this fails because the directory already exists, continue on as if nothing happened. If this fails because of some other reason, for example a network error, I want to stop execution of the program.

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
import com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException;

ChannelSftp sftpClient;
//...
try {
    sftpClient.mkdir("test")
} catch (SftpException e) {
    System.out.println(e.id); // Prints "Failure"
    System.out.println(e.getMessage()); // Prints "null"
    assert (e.id == ChannelSftp.SSH_FX_FAILURE);
    assert (e.id == 4);
}
```

The ID for this failure is `4`.

I noticed that if I `mkdir` inside a directory where I don't have permissions, the exception's id will be `3`/`SSH_FX_PERMISSION_DENIED`.

How can I determine if the `mkdir` failed because the directory was already created?

Is it safe to assume that if the id is 4, then the failure was due to the folder already existing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jsch implements [SFTP version 3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-02). [Section 7 of that RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-02#section-7) defines responses from the SFTP server to the client, including status codes. Here's the list:

```
    #define SSH_FX_OK                            0
    #define SSH_FX_EOF                           1
    #define SSH_FX_NO_SUCH_FILE                  2
    #define SSH_FX_PERMISSION_DENIED             3
    #define SSH_FX_FAILURE                       4
    #define SSH_FX_BAD_MESSAGE                   5
    #define SSH_FX_NO_CONNECTION                 6
    #define SSH_FX_CONNECTION_LOST               7
    #define SSH_FX_OP_UNSUPPORTED                8
```

The RFC says that `SSH_FX_FAILURE` is returned any time there's no more specific error code. Getting it for `mkdir()` doesn't specifically mean that there's already a directory with the requested name. I expect you'd get it if there's a *file* with the expected name, for example. Or if you're trying to make a directory on a read-only filesystem.

[ChannelSftp](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html) has two functions named [stat()](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#stat(java.lang.String)) and [lstat()](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#lstat(java.lang.String)) which can be used to get information about a file or directory. When your mkdir() call fails with SSH_FX_FAILURE, you could call `stat()` on the path to see if the file actually exists and if it's a directory.